# Inserting stored procedure parameter to table only inserts first letter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure where I have parameter with datatype `sql_variant`. This parameter is then converted and inserted into parameter that is `nvarchar(MAX)` datatype. Inserting dates and floats are working fine. Then as example inserting into `varchar(60)` cell doesn't seem to work and only inserts first letter. When I add `SELECT` statements for the parameters in stored procedure it shows after executing the information to be inserted correctly and it only fails the actual insertion to table.

How to insert whole `nvarchar` to `varchar(60`) or similar cell?

Here are important parts of the code without too much extra:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name 
                 @param1 nvarchar(30), 
                 @param2 nvarchar(30), 
                 @param3 sql_variant
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @update_param nvarchar(MAX);
SET @update_param = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @param3);

-- Lots of not important stuff here such as getting datatype from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Sql = N' DECLARE @variable ' + QUOTENAME(@datatype) + N' = @update_param '
         + N' UPDATE table_name'
         + N' SET ' + @param1 + N' = @variable '
         + N' WHERE something = ' + @param2    

Exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@update_param nvarchar(MAX)', @update_param
```

Adding `SELECT @Sql` to the procedure gives following result:

```
DECLARE @variable [varchar] = @update_param  
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = @variable 
WHERE something = thingsome
```

When `@param1 = column_name, @param2 = thingsome`

Edit: I read multiple questions on this topic and they all told to declare nvarchar length. Here I have it declared as `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Edit2: Added code bits.

Edit3: After adding code and help in comments the answer is that there is length undeclared for `@datatype` in `@Sql`

Comment: Sounds like somewhere you haven't declared the length of your `(n)varchar`, tus it's defaulted to an `(n)varchar(1)`. Without the code, that's all we can guess at.

Comment: @Larnu I will add some code, thanks for tip

Comment: @Larnu Would you please take another look?

Comment: `DECLARE @variable [varchar] = @update_param `

Comment: Beat me to it @Diado

Comment: Thanks @Diado and @Larnu, that seems to have done it, I added (MAX) after the `@datatype`. Do you know if this (MAX) will become problematic if added to other kind of datatypes like date, datetime, bit or float?

Comment: Yep, it'll throw an `invalid data type` exception

Comment: @Diado Okay, I'm thinking best course of action is then to make `CASE` to check if `datatype` is such type that has length requirement?

Comment: If you're getting the data type from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` you can check the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column - for `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` it'll be set to `-1`. For values less than `MAX` it'll be the actual value. For `INT` and other data types that it's not relevant to it'll be `NULL`

Comment: @Diado Makes sense, thank you for the help!

Comment: @veix you don't need that `DECLARE @variable` just use `+ N' SET ' + @param1 + N' = @update_param `. The WHERE clause should be `' WHERE something = '@param2;'` too, and @param2 should be passed as another parameter. If you want to *cast* the parameter value, either do it *before* you pass the value to `sp_executesql` or put an explicit `CAST()` call.

Comment: @Larnu I have no intention of writing that for the millionth time. *BUT* that reminded me that `@param1` needs quoting otherwise it will fail for columns that contain spaces

Comment: I misread your comment, but just noticed that as well.

Comment: @veix OK, I'll write it. If you want to generate a script, do that and *check it* for correctness.. Don't try to execute the statements like this. In production code there's no reason to create stored procedures like this - just update the column! The only valid reason for such a stored procedure would be (a) scripting and (b) a bad design - a stored procedure that tries to "hide" the actual update operation. It's easier and safer to use eg LINQ or Dapper on the client side

Comment: @veix that `SET @update_param = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @param3);` is either a bug or an unnecessary conversion. What if the parameter is a *date* or *decimal*? How will it be converted to a string? Will that format match the target column's collation? Why not pass it as a parameter to `sp_executesql` directly?

Comment: Seems like you've got your self quite a mess there. 
This is a clear case of an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
I really don't think that this question can be answered as is since it's missing code in the stored procedure. However, from the code you did post, seems like you are attempting to do something you shouldn't do. So instead of asking questions about the *wrong* solution to the problem, ask a question about the *actual* problem you want to solve.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you, I got the answer for the problem I have here. However like you said, I got quite a mess here. The question is answered for my case, but there are plenty of other problems and I probably have to revisit my stored procedure entirely and most likely create another question (if answer not found otherwise) to help me with my mess.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question at hand, however, the SP you have is open to injection. Raw string concatenation like that is a dangerous game to play. This is far safer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name 
                 @param1 nvarchar(30), 
                 @param2 nvarchar(30), 
                 @param3 sql_variant
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @update_param nvarchar(MAX);
SET @update_param = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @param3);

-- Lots of not important stuff here such as getting datatype from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Sql = N' DECLARE @variable ' + QUOTENAME(@datatype) + N' = @dupdate_param' --Where is the value of @datatype coming from?
         + N' UPDATE table_name'
         + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@param1) + N' = @variable '
         + N' WHERE something = @dparam2;'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@dupdate_param nvarchar(MAX), @dparam2 nvarchar(30)',@dupdate_param = @update_param, @dparam = @param2;

GO
```

Comment: There's no reason to declare `@variable` it only results in an implicit cast *and* introduced the truncation error. `dupdate_param` could be used in the `SET` clause directly

Comment: Come to think of that, `SET @update_param = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @param3);` is probably a bug as well - if it's `@param3` is a `sql_variant` why not pass it as-is? Why convert it to `nvarchar(max)` first, then back to the original type? It's far more likely that `@param3` will contain a correct value

Comment: OK, I got a headache. This could cause more trouble than I thought at first

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree on these points. I was purely addressing the injection issue. There are several *"odd"* choices on the logic here, however, injection is the worst of them. Fixing that should be the most important one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos @Larnu I see  your points and want to thank for the feedback, I clearly have to revisit my logic to avoid risk of injection. I also have to check again how well the other datatypes work. The code I provided is bit simplified, in reality most of the information is parametrized (table name, column name, both parameters after the `SET` and `WHERE`) so the procedure can be used for multiple tables (which may be normalized or flat).